# How enter symbols in VS Code for Lean (macOS)

Tags: visual-studio-code, lean

I'm using Lean in VS Code under macOS Catalina with a U.S. keyboard. How do I enter symbols such as for the implication arrow, union, intersection, subset?

Is there some built-in or add-on palette to facilitate this? Or do I have to use Option key combinations and, if so, where do I find the appropriate codes?

Answer (score 5):

From the [Lean reference](https://leanprover.github.io/reference/using_lean.html#features):

> You can enter Unicode characters with a backslash. For example, `\a` inserts an `α`.

Here are some ways to get the symbol codes:

- **Guess.** Many of the symbols have intuitive names, like `\union` or `\cup` for `⋃`.
- **Use the tooltip.** If you already have the symbol, then hovering over it will reveal the code.

  - If you don't have the symbol, right click > *Go to definition* on a related symbol will often land you close by.
- If all else fails, check [`translations.json`](https://github.com/leanprover/vscode-lean/blob/master/src/abbreviation/abbreviations.json). You can usually get away with guessing, though.

Comment: You can also select and hover over a character to see how to insert it.

Comment: Is there some VS Code plug-in that provides a palette for selecting those characters. (It seems very wasteful of screen space to have to have a separate window open with the translations.json page.

Comment: @ChristopherHughes: Huh? Where do I find, say, a cap symbol (for set union) to hover over so as to discover what input to type to get it?

Comment: If you're using anyone else's Lean code, this is a very handy tip. If you're using set union, then the symbol will be in the relevant library file. Alternatively paste it from somewhere else.

Comment: You can always guess. Without viewing the list, I surmised that `\cap` would enter a set union symbol. And I was right.

Comment: @murray I've expanded on how to find the symbol codes; hope this helps. From experience, I've never had to refer to `translations.json`; guessing and "go to definition" have been enough.

Comment: The `translations.json` file has been moved [here](https://github.com/leanprover/vscode-lean/blob/master/src/abbreviation/abbreviations.json).

Answer (score 1):

⟶ System preferences
⟶ Keyboard
⟶ Input Sources Tab
⟶ `+` at bottom left
⟶ add and select `Unicode Hex Input`
      from panel on right
 ⟶ enter unicode characters via  `alt`+`[code]`
⟶  example, to enter the sign for union, hold down `Alt` and press `222a`

To find additional codes, you can simply Google search `Unicode Union` for example, and it's almost always the first hit
https://www.google.com/search?q=unicode+Union&oq=unicode+Union&aqs=chrome..69i57.3027j0j7&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8

Comment: That does not seem to be of use: after I added that input source and open the keyboard viewer for Unicode Hex Input, what I see looks like the ordinary English keyboard. How do I see keys to press for various symbols, such as the math symbol cap (for union)?

Comment: Yes, the keyboard looks like English, but it now allows input of any unicode character. See edit above

Comment: I use as part of my daily work flow for Greek letters, mathematical symbols, arrows, etc.  Seems initially inconvenient, but you quickly build a repertoire of symbols, and then it is second nature and quite useful to have the actual characters available and in line